Prove that $XY-YX\in \mathfrak{g}$ if $X,Y\in \mathfrak{g}$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of a matrix Lie group $G$.

Definition $3.18$. Let $G$ be a matrix Lie group (a closed subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$). The Lie algebra of $G$, denoted $\mathfrak{g}$, is the set of all matrices $X$ such that $e^{tX}$ is in $G$ for all real numbers $t$.


Theorem $3.20$. Let $G$ be a matrix Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. If $X$ and $Y$ are elements of $\mathfrak{g}$, the following results hold:


$(1)$ $sX\in\mathfrak{g}$ for all real numbers $s$;
$(2)$ $X+Y\in\mathfrak{g}$;
$(3)$ $XY-YX\in\mathfrak{g}$.

Proof of $(3)$:
$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{tX}Ye^{-tX})|_{t=0}=(XY)e^0+(e^0Y)(-X)=XY-YX$. From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we know that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a real subspace of $M_n({\mathbb{C}})$, from which it follows that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a closed subset of $M_n({\mathbb{C}})$, thus $XY-YX=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{hX}Ye^{-tX}-Y}{h}$ belongs to $\mathfrak{g}$. QED
Question:
$(1)$: Why $\mathfrak{g}$ is a real vector space implies that it is closed in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$? I have read this post and I do not quite understand José Carlos Santos's answer, how to deduce from the third line to the fourth line? Or, whether there are other ways to prove this.
$(2)$: Why we can deduce that $XY-YX\in \mathfrak{g}$ if $\mathfrak{g}$ is a closed subset of $M_n({\mathbb{C}})$?
Any help is appreciated.

The answer that you have linked from José Carlos Santos uses that, if $V$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$, then $V$ is closed in $\mathbb{C}^n$ because (as mentioned in the second answer by Blazej) any finite dimensional subspace is a closed subset (alternatively these notes). Therefore, since $\frak{g}$ is a subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, which is finite dimensional, $\frak{g}$ is therefore a finite dimensional subspace and is therefore closed in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.
Once we know that $\frak{g}$ is a closed set, we know that closed sets contain their limit points, therefore since in your proof of (3) you have written $XY-YX$ as a limit point of $\frak{g}$, it must be contained in $\frak{g}$ as it is closed. Let me know if this answers your question.

Hello, could you explain José Carlos Santos's answer? I do not understand how he deduced the result from the third line. Also, for "these notes", the link seems not work.

You have a basis ${e_1, \ldots, e_n}$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$. The set $V$ is the subspace spanned by ${e_1, \ldots, e_k}$. Therefore, it is a vector space, and it is a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$. This is what the "third line" contributes. Then, from the third line, you apply the fact that finite-dimensional subspaces are closed subsets to deduce that $V$ is closed. Now replace $V$ with $\frak{g}$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. This is the first paragraph in the original answer, but let me know what is confusing. The link works for me...

Maybe because you are student in UCLA?

I am not a student at UCLA, nor is this the point here: the notes are only meant to address the fact that finite dimensional subspaces are closed sets, which the linked stack exchange post also proves. Conditioned on this fact being true, do you understand the proof?

I have seen the proof, it's more "analysis" than "algebra", I wonder whether there is a proof using topology.

@Bowei: the distinction between "analysis" and "topology" here is beside the point. Do you believe that a line is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$? Do you believe that a plane is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$? Visualize both of these carefully. It is just a straightforward generalization of this.

@QiaochuYuan Thank you. Very enlightening.
